# Return Response JSON doesn't work on Laravel Lumen

Tags: php, json, laravel, debugging, lumen

I have setup a fresh Lumen on my host. The error log works for hitting on a wrong route, but it doesn't work if I try to return a json response (when I try as a return on a POST response).

I tried writing this on my `Controller.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function createErrorResponse($message, $code)
    { 
        // print("A");  // works
       return response()->json(['message' => $message, 'code' => $code], $code);
    }
}
```

I tried calling above function on another controller.

```
 if (error) {
    // var_dump("A");  // works
    // return "A";    // doesn't work
    // having print on createErrorResponse also works..

    return $this->createErrorResponse('Error on data.', 560);
 }
```

But returning JSON doesn't. It also doesn't return "A" with `return "A"`. It only returns var_dump.

I also tried `chmod -R 777 storage/` but it didn't change anything either.

Comment: What the error said? Would you mind to include the stack trace in your question?